# How do exchanges calculate EMA in real-time?

Tags: math, graph, trading, cryptocurrency, mathematical-expressions

**I calculated the EMA of some candles,but i don't know how to calculate the EMA for a unclosed candle**
**i came up with this idea but it doesn't correspond to one in the exchange**
n = EMA_lenght

> EMA_FOR_UNCLOSED_CANDLE = Close*(2/(n+1))+last_EMAn * (1-(2/(n+1)))